# Arbitrary/Infinite precision variables - C#

Tags: c#, variables, arbitrary-precision

Is there any type in C#that would allow me to store a fractional number with arbitrary or infinite precision? I don't want to use any external libraries--would I have to write a class myself? How would I do this?

I need a variable to which I can apply the standard arithmetic operations, and get the result with as much precision as I want, something in which I could do something like calculate pi or another irrational number to a precision like 10,000 digits...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't want to use any external libraries--would I have to write a class myself?

I don't really get why would you implement a new library instead of using an existing one. But I would then suggest the [BigRational](http://bcl.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BigRational&referringTitle=Home) library of Microsoft. Source codes are available as well. It uses the `BigInteger` type internally.

Comment: Rolling your own library is guaranteed to run into issues that other libraries have already encountered and solved.